A copy of 'Default', 'Sam', 'Security', 'Software', 'System'
I would like to make a copy the aforementioned files -  'Default', 'Sam', 'Security', 'Software', 'System'. all of these are under
"C:\Windows\System32\Config"
It seems like mission impossible.
I get some error about the files are being used by some other process.
Also tried
Reg Export "HKLM\Default" "E:\RegBack\Default.reg"
Reg Export "HKLM\Sam" "E:\RegBack\Sam.reg"
Reg Export "HKLM\Security" "E:\RegBack\Security.reg"
Reg Export "HKLM\Software" "E:\RegBack\Software.reg"
Reg Export "HKLM\System" "E:\RegBack\System.reg"
I also tried POWERSHELL copying one of my restore points but the terminal says it can not find the target.
$Source = "\\MYPC\root\default:SystemRestore.SequenceNumber=218"
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination


The safe way to copy any and all information from an active (mounted) drive is to use Windows' VSS (Volume Shadow Copy Service). This makes a snapshot of the drive as it exists at a specific instant, and prevents that snapshot from changing, though there may be changes to the file system.
The easiest way to do this is through third-party software, such as disk imaging tools like Macrium Reflect Free or 30-day trial, AOMEI Backupper, or an alternative.

Make a complete drive image, or just an image of the Windows partition.
Mount the image (it will appear as if it were another drive) to access those restricted folders.

The alternative is to boot from other media, e.g., Ubuntu Live. That requires making the boot media, booting from it, and copying files to another drive.

Thanx.
In the meantime I've managed to copy the 5 files under windows recovery-cmd console.
I had no other choice but to restart to advanced boot options- recovery.
Thanx
